# Accessing variable from another function in a function while using class() method

Tags: python, class, tkinter

I'm wondering if there is any ways to access variable through different functions?  Below is my code, Inside isWinner(), I want to access text of my buttons. How could it be done?[image]

```
class ttt():
    master = 0
    player1 = 0
    player2 = 0
    bclick = True
    buttonCounter = 1
    win = 0
    lose = 0

    def boardDisplay(self):
        button1 = tk.Button(self.master, text=" ", command=lambda: self.buttonClick(button1), height=4, width=10)
        button1.place(x=275, y=150)
        button2 = tk.Button(self.master, text=" ", command=lambda: self.buttonClick(button2), height=4, width=10)
        button2.place(x=355, y=150)
        button3 = tk.Button(self.master, text=" ", command=lambda: self.buttonClick(button3), height=4, width=10)
        button3.place(x=435, y=150)
        button4 = tk.Button(self.master, text=" ", command=lambda: self.buttonClick(button4), height=4, width=10)
        button4.place(x=275, y=230)
        button5 = tk.Button(self.master, text=" ", command=lambda: self.buttonClick(button5), height=4, width=10)
        button5.place(x=355, y=230)
        button6 = tk.Button(self.master, text=" ", command=lambda: self.buttonClick(button6), height=4, width=10)
        button6.place(x=435, y=230)
        button7 = tk.Button(self.master, text=" ", command=lambda: self.buttonClick(button7), height=4, width=10)
        button7.place(x=275, y=310)
        button8 = tk.Button(self.master, text=" ", command=lambda: self.buttonClick(button8), height=4, width=10)
        button8.place(x=355, y=310)
        button9 = tk.Button(self.master, text=" ", command=lambda: self.buttonClick(button9), height=4, width=10)
        button9.place(x=435, y=310)

    def buttonClick(self, button):
        if button["text"] == " " and self.bclick == True:
            button["text"] = "X"
            self.bclick = False
            self.isWinner()
            self.buttonCounter += 1
        elif button["text"] == " " and self.bclick == False:
            button["text"] = "O"
            self.bclick = True
            self.isWinner()
            self.buttonCounter += 1
        else:
            tk.messagebox.showinfo("Tic Tac Toe", "Button is clicked already!")

    def isWinner(self):
```

Comment: declare a `self` variable

Comment: @r0ei I tried that it returns me an error. So inside my isWinner() function, I tried to write self.button1["text"] == "X" or self.boardDisplay().button1["text"] it will not work somehow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to write `self` before your buttons **every** time. When you very first declare something on `self` it actually gets instantiated in `self.__dict__`. Calling `self` is just shorthand. That being said, when you made your buttons you did not stick them in the `__dict__` so they weren't there. If you ever wonder if you have messed up with a `self`, simply `print(self.__dict__)`. If it isn't there then you didn't declare it on `self`. I am speaking of `instances` not `methods`. In other words, `button9` is an instance, `boardDisplay` is not.

```
class ttt():
    master = 0
    player1 = 0
    player2 = 0
    bclick = True
    buttonCounter = 1
    win = 0
    lose = 0

    def boardDisplay(self):
        self.button1 = tk.Button(self.master, text=" ", command=lambda: self.buttonClick(button1), height=4, width=10)
        self.button1.place(x=275, y=150)
        self.button2 = tk.Button(self.master, text=" ", command=lambda: self.buttonClick(button2), height=4, width=10)
        self.button2.place(x=355, y=150)
        self.button3 = tk.Button(self.master, text=" ", command=lambda: self.buttonClick(button3), height=4, width=10)
        self.button3.place(x=435, y=150)
        self.button4 = tk.Button(self.master, text=" ", command=lambda: self.buttonClick(button4), height=4, width=10)
        self.button4.place(x=275, y=230)
        self.button5 = tk.Button(self.master, text=" ", command=lambda: self.buttonClick(button5), height=4, width=10)
        self.button5.place(x=355, y=230)
        self.button6 = tk.Button(self.master, text=" ", command=lambda: self.buttonClick(button6), height=4, width=10)
        self.button6.place(x=435, y=230)
        self.button7 = tk.Button(self.master, text=" ", command=lambda: self.buttonClick(button7), height=4, width=10)
        self.button7.place(x=275, y=310)
        self.button8 = tk.Button(self.master, text=" ", command=lambda: self.buttonClick(button8), height=4, width=10)
        self.button8.place(x=355, y=310)
        self.button9 = tk.Button(self.master, text=" ", command=lambda: self.buttonClick(button9), height=4, width=10)
        self.button9.place(x=435, y=310)

    def buttonClick(self, button):
        if button["text"] == " " and self.bclick == True:
            button["text"] = "X"
            self.bclick = False
            self.isWinner()
            self.buttonCounter += 1
        elif button["text"] == " " and self.bclick == False:
            button["text"] = "O"
            self.bclick = True
            self.isWinner()
            self.buttonCounter += 1
        else:
            tk.messagebox.showinfo("Tic Tac Toe", "Button is clicked already!")

    def isWinner(self):
        print(self.button9['text'])
```

You should rename `boardDisplay` to `__init__`. Classes generally have what is called a `constructor`. In python `__init__` is how you declare a constructor. This way when you instantiate `ttt()`, what you are really doing is calling it's `__init__`

Really your code should be like this:

```
import tkinter as tk

#tell this class that it is an extension of tk.Tk ~ the root
class App(tk.Tk):
    #class constructor ~ hit when you do App()
    def __init__(self):
        #init the class that App extended ~ this is also know as the superclass
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)

        self.player1 = 0
        self.player2 = 0
        self.bclick = True
        self.buttonCounter = 1
        self.win = 0
        self.lose = 0

        #make all of your stuff
        #notice ------------------v ~ the master of this button is now the root
        self.button1 = tk.Button(self, text=" ", height=4, width=10)
        #you should let it finish creating itself before you dump it in a lambda
        self.button1.configure(command=lambda: self.buttonClick(self.button1))
        self.button1.place(x=275, y=150)

        #etc....

    def buttonClick(self, button):
        if button["text"] == " " and self.bclick == True:
            button["text"] = "X"
            self.bclick = False
            self.isWinner()
            self.buttonCounter += 1
        elif button["text"] == " " and self.bclick == False:
            button["text"] = "O"
            self.bclick = True
            self.isWinner()
            self.buttonCounter += 1
        else:
            tk.messagebox.showinfo("Tic Tac Toe", "Button is clicked already!")

    def isWinner(self):
        print(self.button9['text'])


if "__main__" == __name__:
    app = App()
    app.title("Tic-Tac-Toe")
    app.mainloop()
```

You can use this as a base template for any OOP `tkinter` app.

```
import tkinter as tk


class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = App()
    app.title("My Application")
    app.geometry('800x600')
    app.mainloop()
```

Comment: self.button1 = tk.Button(self.master, text=" ", command=lambda: self.buttonClick(button1), height=4, width=10)
NameError: name 'button1' is not defined
it still returns error

Comment: @AlexHu ~ read my edit and restructure your code accordingly. I understand you are new and things are confusing, but you are starting on the wrong foot.

Comment: Thank you! I'm beginner it actually takes time to understand! But big help!

Comment: @AlexHu ~ I added an edit. Read the very bottom of my post

Comment: @AlexHu - If you want to see what a fully functional tic-tac-toe made in tkinter, with OOP, looks like see the below link. I used a bunch of concepts in an easy to understand way that can help you get better. https://stackoverflow.com/a/63149190/10292330

Answer (score 0):

you would add a button pass to your buttonClick function

```
   def buttonClick(self, button):
    if button["text"] == " " and self.bclick == True:
        button["text"] = "X"
        self.bclick = False
        self.isWinner(button)
        self.buttonCounter += 1
    elif button["text"] == " " and self.bclick == False:
        button["text"] = "O"
        self.bclick = True
        self.isWinner(button)
        self.buttonCounter += 1
    else:
        tk.messagebox.showinfo("Tic Tac Toe", "Button is clicked already!")
```

you would also add the passed button to the isWinner function

```
def isWinner(self, button):
```

Comment: Sorry, I did not clear my question, So I have 9 buttons, every time I clicked one of my button in the program that I created, it will add either a "X" or an "O", three of them in a row will decide the winner, so, I cannot check it one by one. It's a tic tac toc game program

Comment: could you tell me what happens when you click the button

Comment: it will add a "X" or an"O" on button.

Comment: sorry i need to go i will get back to you later

Answer (score 0):

Define a subclass for your buttons which defines a method to call when clicked.  Much of the work done in `ttt` can be delegated to the subclass as well. Each instance of the subclass keeps a reference to is "container" (in this case, an instance of `ttt`).

```
class ttt():
    master = 0
    player1 = 0
    player2 = 0
    bclick = True
    buttonCounter = 1
    win = 0
    lose = 0

    def boardDisplay(self):
        button1 = MyButton(self, x=275, y=150)
        button2 = MyButton(self, x=355, y=150)
        button3 = MyButton(self, x=435, y=150)
        button4 = MyButton(self, x=275, y=230)
        button5 = MyButton(self, x=355, y=230)
        button6 = MyButton(self, x=435, y=230)
        button7 = MyButton(self, x=275, y=310)
        button8 = MyButton(self, x=355, y=310)
        button9 = MyButton(self, x=435, y=310)


class MyButton(tk.Button):
    def __init__(self, container, x, y, h=4, w=10):
        super().__init__(container.master, " ", command=self.onClick, height=h, width=w)
        self.container = container
        self.place(x, y)

    def onClick(self):
        if self["text" != " ":
            tk.messagebox.showinfo("Tic Tac Toe", "Button is clicked already!")
        elif self.container.bclick:
            self["text"] = "X"
            self.container.bclick = False
            self.container.isWinner()
            self.container.buttonCounter += 1
        else:
            self["text"] = "O"
            self.container.bclick = True
            self.container.isWinner()
            self.container.buttonCounter += 1
```

Comment: I'm wondering if I can do this in one class, to be honest, I'm a python beginner, I feel like your code is hard to understand, no offense. Is there any ways that I could do it based on code that I have right now?